# Issue with borrowing in Rust

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm starting to learn Rust, I apologize if the question seems trivial.

This is the code I have:

```rs
struct File {
    name: String,
    size: u32
}

struct Dir {
    name: String,
    files: Vec<File>,
    dirs: Vec<Dir>
}

impl Dir {
    fn get_subfolder(&mut self, subfolder: String) -> &Dir {
        let mut matched: Option<&Dir> = None;

        for elem in &self.dirs {
            if elem.name == subfolder {
                matched = Some(elem);
                break;
            }
        }

        match matched {
            Some(dir) => {
                return dir;
            },
            None => {
                let new_dir: Dir = Dir {name: subfolder, files: vec!(), dirs: vec!()};
                self.dirs.push(new_dir);
                return self.dirs.last().unwrap();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I get an error on `self.dirs.push(new_dir)`.

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `self.dirs` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src\main.rs:29:17
   |
13 |     fn get_subfolder(&mut self, subfolder: String) -> &Dir {
   |                      - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
16 |         for elem in &self.dirs {
   |                     ---------- immutable borrow occurs here
...
25 |                 return dir;
   |                        --- returning this value requires that `self.dirs` is borrowed for `'1`
...
29 |                 self.dirs.push(new_dir);
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
```

From what i understand, the compiler is telling me that the vector `dirs` is borrowed when returning the `dir` reference in the `Some(dir)` arm of the match expression. And it tells me that the borrow lasts for as long as `self` lives (i.e. they have the same lifetimes).
It then complains that I'm borrowing `dirs` mutably in the other arm, `None`. But these two arms could never get executed in a single call, right? There's no way that an `Option` is both `Some<T>` and `None`, so I'm always either borrowing the vector for as long as `self` lives, or I'm borrowing it for just one line to append a new `Dir` to it.

What's going on here? Is my reasoning correct?

Edit: it seems that this is a limitation of the current borrow checker. Are there any "elegant" workarounds to this?
One that comes to mind is returning a copy of the object, but I can't really do that here.

Comment: Yes, it is a known flaw in the borrow checker.

Comment: Maybe the `match` expression is allowing the borrows to outlive the function call, but since you're returning a reference, the borrows have to be valid for the entire duration of the function call.

Comment: Also, take a look at this [post](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/lifetime-problem-returning-reference-to-existing-or-new-element-of-container/62874) in URLO.